# Swift variables on Collectionviewcontroller resetting after calling a function from outside

Tags: ios, swift, function, collectionview

When I am calling a function on `CollectionCiewController` with button on `CollectionViewHeader`, it makes all variables nil on `c.view`. I couldn't find out where the problem is.

```
 @IBAction func loadmore(_ sender: Any) {
        CollectionViewController().goNetwork()  
    }
```

called func:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 var query: QueryForUnogs!
 var dataSource = [REsult]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.goNetwork()
}

func goNetwork() {
        var urlWithParams: String = "https://unogsng.p.rapidapi.com/search?start_year=\(query.minYear!)&end_year=\(query.maxYear!)&start_rating=\(query.minImdb!)&offset=\(self.offset.description)&type=\(query.type!)&end_rating=10&countrylist=\(query.cc!)&orderby=\(query.orderby!)&audio=\(query.audio!)&subtitle=\(query.subtitle!)"

    NetworkService().downloadUnogs(_qu: urlWithParams) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        case .success(let RR):
        self.dataSource = RR.results!
}}}}
```

Comment: are you getting data in `RR.results` ?

Comment: in which controller you are doing this ? @IBAction func loadmore(_ sender: Any) {
        CollectionViewController().goNetwork()  
    }

Comment: i am calling this from footer. CollectionReusableView

Comment: can you post that code and class ?

Comment: `class CollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var loadBtn: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func loadmore(_ sender: Any) {
        let cvc = CollectionViewController() as CollectionViewController
        cvc.goNetwork()
    }"`  i tried this but not works

Comment: why you are calling `goNetwork()` from `CollectionReusableView` ?

Comment: why not calling it from `CollectionViewController` ? is there any reason i want to understand

Comment: because button is on the footer. and its action is there. i am getting response from api without problem. but when i want to load more<its meaning new query> and call the same func i get error. i see why i get error because all variables are resetting to nil.

Comment: you need to implement delegate in your CollectionViewController to get button click event ...

Comment: where you are assigning `CollectionReusableView` to your collectionView?

Comment: in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` right ?

Comment: from storyboard

Comment: ```override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
         if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter) {
                   let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "LoadFooter", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView
                           
                   return footerView
        }
        fatalError()
    }```

Comment: i tried to call another simple function there from footer. same result.  it makes all variables to nil

Comment: okay .. i am posting a solution for you .. give me 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling function on new instance of `CollectionViewController` thats why getting everything nil... get the current `CollectionViewController` through delegate and call goNetwork on that existing `CollectionViewController` object

Write a protocol like this

```
protocol CollectionHeaderViewDelegate {
  func didTapButton()
}
```

Write `CollectionReusableView` class with delegate

```
class CollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

  @IBOutlet weak var loadBtn: UIButton!
  var delegate: CollectionHeaderViewDelegate?

  @IBAction func loadmore(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didTapButton()

  }

}
```

And in your main Controller class which is `CollectionViewController`
Write this function

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter) {
      let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "LoadFooter", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView
      footerView.delegate = self
      return footerView

    }
    fatalError()

  }
```

Write extension of `CollectionViewController` and confirm it with protocol

```
extension CollectionViewController: CollectionHeaderViewDelegate {
  func didTapButton() {
     goNetwork()
  }


}
```

Now you have goNetwork in your main controller .... it will load contents automatically ...

**thanks**

Comment: it works. no resetting now. thanks for that great solution